# Change cookie value onclick

Tags: magento, cookies

Sorry if this is really obvious, not great at coding and new to cookies so stil trying to get my head round it. I am trying to create a website redirect for my Magento installation. In the index.php I have placed the following code which checks the users IP location, directs them to the correct website and sets a cookie. If a cookie is already set it takes the value from the cookie and directs to a website based on this.

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE['penstore']) )){

     $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = $_COOKIE['penstore'];
     $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website"; 
} 
else 
{ 

include("geoip.inc");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "$ip");

geoip_close($gi);

switch($country_code)

{ case "CA": case "US":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "usa";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
setcookie("penstore",'usa',time()+43200);
break;
  case "GB":
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "uk";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
setcookie("penstore",'uk',time()+43200);
break;
  default:
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] = "int";
$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] = "website";
setcookie("penstore",'int',time()+43200);
}
}
```

This all appears to work okay, my problem is finding a way to allow customers to change websites by clicking an image in the header. I have tried several different methods based on code found on the web and this site but I can't get any of it to work.  I currently have the following code in my header.phtml:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    location.reload();
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('penstore','int',30)"><img src="http://mysite.com/images/INT.gif"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('penstore','usa',30)"><img src="http://mysite.com/images/US.gif"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('penstore','uk',30)"><img src="http://mysite.com/images/GB.gif"></a>
```

The idea is that the customer clicks on the image which causes the cookie value to be updated and the current page to be reloaded, which based on the code in the index.php, would cause a different website to load. All that happens is the # gets added to the url?

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to switch websites, not stores, so can't use Magento store switcher.

Comment: All you need to do is allow client to change stores? Magento has built in functionality for this (using a dropdown menu - you can try to mimic this functionality using an image, but I would stick to the built in method). BTW: Magento has its own Stack Site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, need to change website, not store. Don't believe Magento has this feature. Thanks for the link, didn't know that existed.

Comment: you said: "directs them to the correct store" and "my problem is finding a way to allow customers to change stores by clicking an image in the header". Sounds like you need to read up Magento's definition of what Website and Store means. You can change both using Magento. See BrazilianFightwear.com for example. You connect to .com.br if you are in Brazil or .com if you are anywhere else. Find a proxy in Brazil to see for yourself.